# Batch job not stopping with stop commandLineJobRunner

Tags: java, spring

Command buid with application to start job:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9875 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:/Users/rishabh/Desktop/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:/Users/rishabh/Desktop/jmx.access -cp C:\Users\rishabh\slave-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner application-context.xml sampleJob correlationId=71925ee3-4879-4dee-8177-fa347893df88
```

Now when I am trying to stop this job with '-stop' argument like this:

```
java -cp C:\Users\rishabh.pandey\slave-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -stop application-context.xml sampleJob
```

This gives:

> Job terminated in error no running execution found for job=sampleJob
>   with JobexecutionNotRunningException

Please provide the sample command example. I also want repository state stable for job data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fetched the correlationId repository and then run the command with specific correlationId.
earlier i was using job name and new correlationId and it was looking with correlationID that was not in job repository.